# What hook is executed just after wp_query has been executed?

Tags: hooks, title

What hook is executed just after wp_query has been executed? before template is rendered? I want to change the page title but it depends on what has been queried.

I have put it in template_redirect but not sure if it is the right hook

Comment: probably https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_posts/ would be the best hook for doing anything right after an posts query

Answer (score 2):

There are [a few actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) that can technically be used (including `template_redirect`), but a more appropriate action seems to be [the_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/the_post); It passes the post object by reference making alterations easy:

```
function my_action( $post_obj ) {
    $post_obj->post_title = "New Title"
}

add_action( 'the_post', 'my_action' );
```

If you only need to change the title, you could also take a look at the [the_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title) filter.

Comment: Your answer would have been very helpful had the OP asked about the post title. But they asked about the page title...

Comment: @LeaCohen When you are on a single page, the page title **is** the post title. A page is simply a [built-in post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). `the_post` action is fired for pages and `$post_obj` will contain all the information for that page just like a post.

Comment: You're right, but who said they're on a single page?

Comment: @LeaCohen I used that as an example. It will work for ***any*** page data from ***any*** query. In the back-end, posts and pages are the exact same thing (post-types). After a query, a post object is created (whether it be a post, page, or custom post-type). `the_post` is the best action to use to alter the page's data because it exposes that object. Effectively, my answer is the same as Craig's; that the template_redirect action is one of several that technically can be used. I'm simply pointing out the most useful action for the OP's situation.

Comment: But what if it's an archive page?

Comment: @LeaCohen Like you asked earlier, who said they're on an archive page? That being said, archive pages are fine. When I said ***any*** query I meant ***any*** query. The description for `the_post` is quite literally: `allows developers to modify the post object immediately after being queried and setup`. Pages are stored and set-up as post objects in the back-end. This is exactly what the OP is looking for. Are these questions based on any actual issues you've run into when using `the_post`?

Comment: No, actually my issue is theoretical rather than practical...

Comment: @LeaCohen Unless I am mistaken, the reason for your downvote was because you mistakenly thought `the_post` action only applied to posts. Now that you know better, do you have any other issues that need to be rectified before changing your vote? I assure you, I have used the `the_post` action as described; it works. This is a perfectly valid answer to the original question. Unless you have some actual experience or knowledge that would indicate that my answer is wrong (and by all means, tell me if you do so I can fix the answer), I fail to see any further issues.

Comment: I'd love to. But I tried your code now, and unless I'm mistaken about the OP's intent, it doesn't do what I understand the OP wants. I understand the "page title" as being what's displayed in the browser window, not inside the page / post.

Comment: @LeaCohen Do you mean the title tag in the head? It isn't ideal, but you can use `the_post` to alter the title tag in the same manner as `template_redirect`. Since the OP asked for an action between `wp_query` and the template rendering, my answer is still technically valid. However, I would assume that on the Stack Exchange devoted to WordPress, when someone says "page title," they usually mean the title of an actual WordPress page. Regardless, unless the OP clarifies his question, I think downvoting an answer based on your own assumption of the OP's intended meaning is a bit unjustified.

Comment: Maybe you're right, sorry. But my downvote is locked now, and I can't remove it unless an edit is made on the post :(. And if you decide to edit the post, perhaps you could add a semicolon after the assignment :).

Answer (score 1):

Yep you're right `template_redirect` is fired right after `wp` which performs the query.

A very useful plugin you might want to look at is: https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

This can help you to see what's loaded on a particular page during development, in addition to what hook is used